# How big team can work on same project

Tags: oop, architecture, software-design

I know how git works. But how do I get architecture that big team can work on a same project without conflicts. Is there any book/tutorial/example about that?

Comment: It is called version control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You partition the system into modules/components/services that are relatively independent and communicate via well-defined interfaces. You can see, for example, [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/twitter-soa) by Jeremy Cloud on how Twitter's architecture evolved to SOA.

Comment: +1 for modules, however I find it will more appealing if provided with some examples about how the modules can benefit the versioning.

Comment: There are two things that work together - managing interfaces and cohesiveness. interfaces should evolve relatively slow and more in a gradual manner (e.g. support previous version until all consumers migrated etc.). As for cohesiveness when the modules are more cohesive the need to change interfaces would be reduced so work can progress on them in a more independent manner

Comment: I'd add that the trick to scaling the size of the team is to divide them up into smaller teams which align with the services @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  That said, the website Lynda.com (subscription required) has a tutorial on Git, name "Git Essential Training."  That course was released in August, 2012.